# C# Events / Interfaces - Getting Callbacks without subscribing in every class that's using the interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, interface

I'm learning about interfaces and events, and so far so good, but I am kinda stuck on one issue.

In my days of using C# interfaces, I'm used to declaring which interface to use, then implementing the methods associated, and they get automatic callbacks whenever an event gets raised.

For example Unity's [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html):

```
using UnityEngine; using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler {
    //Detect if a click occurs
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        //Output to console the clicked GameObject's name and the following message. You can replace this with your own actions for when clicking the GameObject.
        Debug.Log(name + " Game Object Clicked!");
    } }
```

Now, when looking at examples on how to use Events and Interfaces, I am finding the following examples:

Publisher Class & Interface

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Publisher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void ClickAction();
    public static event ClickAction OnClicked;


    void Start()
    {
          OnClicked();
    }

}


public interface IBallManager
{
    void Teleport();

}
```

Subscriber Class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Subscriber : MonoBehaviour, IBallManager
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        Publisher.OnClicked += Teleport;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        Publisher.OnClicked -= Teleport;
    }

    public void Teleport()
    {
        Debug.Log("EventTriggered");
    }

}
```

My question is as follows: How would I build an interface where I don't have to manually subscribe and unsubscribe to an event? Is there a way to implement an interface and not having to use Publisher.OnClicked += Teleport; & Publisher.OnClicked -= Teleport; in every class where I use the IBallManager? Just implementing the interface and getting the automatic callbacks when the event gets raised, like in Unity's IPointerClickHandler.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `IPointerClickHandler` is basically working because it inherits from [IEventSystemHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IEventSystemHandler.html) so uses  the Unity internal EventSystem. Those methods are basically called the same way `Awake` and `OnEnable` are called which works a bit different than usual method calls but are `Messages`

Answer (score 2):

You can't automatically subscribe an event, but you can move your subscribing code to abstract class and inherit it in every class where you want to implement `IBallManager`:

```
public abstract class BaseSubscriber: MonoBehaviour, IBallManager
{
    public virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        Publisher.OnClicked += OnPublisherClicked;
    }

    public virtual void OnDisable()
    {
        Publisher.OnClicked -= OnPublisherClicked;
    }

    protected abstract void OnPublisherClicked();
}
```

Inherit it in your concrete subscriber like it's done below and base class will done subscribing stuff for you:

```
public class Subscriber: BaseSubscriber
{
    public override void OnEnable()
    {
        // Do smth here
        base.OnEnable();
    }

    public override void OnDisable()
    {
        // Do smth here
        base.OnDisable();
    }

    protected override void OnPublisherClicked()
    {
        Debug.Log("EventTriggered");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How would I build an interface where I don't have to manually
>   subscribe and unsubscribe to an event? Is there a way to implement an
>   interface and not having to use Publisher.OnClicked += Teleport; Just implementing the interface and getting the automatic callbacks when the event gets raised, like in Unity's IPointerClickHandler.

Yes.

Your Example interface:

```
public interface IClicker
{
    void Click();
}
```

The class that implements the ineterface:

```
public class Clicker : MonoBehaviour, IClicker
{
    public void Click()
    {

    }
}
```

To invoke the function, find the GameObject the script with the script that implements the interface, get the interface with `GetComponent` and call its function if it's not `null`. If it's `null` then the class did not implement the interface.

```
GameObject targetObj = GameObject.Find("Obj with Interface");
IClicker clicker = targetObj.GetComponent<IClicker>();

if (clicker != null)
    clicker.Click();
```

---

You can also make your interface derive from `IEventSystemHandler`:

```
public interface IClicker : IEventSystemHandler
{
    void Click();
}
```

Then use [`ExecuteEvents.ValidateEventData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.ValidateEventData.html) to validate that class that implements the interface and [`ExecuteEvents.Execute`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute.html) to execute the event. This is harder but is worth knowing.